# MySQL calculate from same value

Tags: mysql

i have this query:

```
SELECT `item_code`, 
       `q_rr`, 
       `q_srs`, 
       @running_bal := @running_bal + (`q_rr` - `q_srs`)  as `Balance`
FROM   records, (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName
order by
      records.item_code,
      records.date
```

which results is:

```
 item_code  |  q_rr  | q_srs |    balance
--------------------------------------------
 0F02206A       2        0           2
 BR00113D       3        0           5
 BR00114D       10       0           15
 BR00114D       0        1           14
 BR00114D       0        1           13
 BR00115D       20       0           33
 BR00115D       0        1           32
 BR00115D       0        1           31
```

need help to make the result to calculate the balance, if q_rr(+) and q_srs(-) and calculate per item_code.

```
 item_code  |  q_rr  | q_srs |    balance
--------------------------------------------
 0F02206A       2        0           2
 BR00113D       3        0           3
 BR00114D       10       0           10
 BR00114D       0        1           9
 BR00114D       0        1           8
 BR00115D       20       0           20
 BR00115D       0        1           19
 BR00115D       0        1           18
```

Comment: could you help create in sqlfiddle and share the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `@code` variable to track `item_code` changes:

```
SELECT
  r.item_code,
  r.q_rr, 
  r.q_srs,
  @running_bal := IF(@code = r.item_code, @running_bal, 0) + (r.q_rr - r.q_srs) as Balance,
  @code := r.item_code AS dummy
FROM
  records r
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT @running_bal := 0, @code := '') tempName
ORDER BY
  r.item_code,
  r.date
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04ef2b/11

You can eliminate `dummy` column by putting this as subquery in another select:

```
SELECT item_code, q_rr, q_srs, Balance
FROM (
  -- there put first query
) r
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04ef2b/12

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `item_code`, 
       `id`, 
       `type`, 
       @running_bal := case when type = 0 then id
       else @running_bal + (`id` - `type`) end as `Balance`
FROM   supportContacts, (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName
order by
      supportContacts.item_code
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c92616/5)